# ModelBuilder, Iterate by Field and Viewshed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, viewshed, iterator

I want to compute the independent Viewshed for 360 different points. If I run these all together, I have one viewshed output which shows how many times any given cell is visible, but this does not tell me WHICH Observer Point these cells are visible from. The Observer Points tool has a limit of only examining 16 points. Therefore, I want to run a single viewshed analysis for every one of my points, and then do post-processing to determine which Point can see which cell. However, these points cover a large area (120km x 30km) , and the viewshed tool is extremely slow. I need to restrict the viewshed for each point to only consider a pre-defined limited portion of the total area.

The data is currently stored as such:

1. Feature class containing all points. Each point has a unique identifier (Image)
2. A folder for each Image (the name of the folder being the Image number), within which is a DEM, which is labelled as DEM%Image%.

The Viewshed Tool needs two inputs: the raster to be analyzed and a point coverage.
I would like to be able to iterate BOTH of these: 
A) iterate by Field so that each point is fed into the Viewshed tool by itself
B) iterate the raster that is used for each image.

I have been trying to use the "Iterate by Field" iterator plugged into the Viewshed tool, but it only lets me set it as a "precondition". Not entirely sure if I am approaching this the right way.

---

Update: I can get the Iterate Feature iterator to populate the "Input Point or Polyline Observer Features" part of the Viewshed Tool, but still trying to work out how to match a unique DEM to each input feature.

Comment: If your DEMs are all uniform another option may be to use Visibility in place of Viewshed since it allows you to select an outer radius. Are you open to using a python script or tool?

Comment: This question seems to have changed from its original so I think you should heavily revise it to try and make what you are asking now clear.